# mydomain.example redirect to mydomain.example/store for Magento store

Tags: magento, redirect

I currently have a domain landing page which I want to get rid of. The landing page (`mydomain.example`) links to a blog and a Magento store (`mydomain.example/store`) but I want to the domain to link directly to the Magento store.

I set up a redirect using my hosting company's domain redirect tool on `mydomain.example` to `mydomain.example/store,` but this results in a redirect loop `mydomain.example/store/store/store/store` etc.

Should I be setting up a redirect anyway? It makes more sense to me to just set my Magento storefront as `mydomain.example` and get rid of the /store on every page within the store.

Comment: are you using any open source like wordpress for blog? or any custom created blog?

Comment: Wordpress. The url for that is mydomain.com/journal. The goal is to  link to the blog from mydomain.com/store rather than having this landing page at mydomain.com.

Comment: As per my understanding, if any use come to mydomain.com first time, it should redirect to mydomain.com/store. am I right?

Comment: Either redirect to mydomain.com/store, or make it so that the store is at mydomain.com without the need for /store at all. I'm not sure which is the *best* solution.

However, when I tried the first solution to redirect mydomain.com to mydomain.com/store, it resulted in a redirect loop. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add jQuery core library and jQuery Cookies library on your WordPress site:

- [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/download/)
- [jQuery Cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Then use this jQuery code in the `header.php` file.

```
var redirectStore = jQuery.cookie("redirect");
if(redirectStore!="yes") {
    jQuery.cookie("redirect", "yes",{path:'/'});
    window.location= "http://www.mydomain.example/store";
}
```

It is checking if a "redirect" cookie is already created or not. First time users will not have this cookie. Then it redirect to `mydomain.example/store` and creates the cookie. If the user comes back to blog site while visiting store then it will find the redirect cookie to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: What if the user doesn't accept cookies? I'd rather figure out what is causing the redirect loop and fix it permanently rather than use cookies.

Comment: If you use domain redirection, then it will stuck in loop. redirect loop issue: On first land you are redirecting to mydomain.com/store, again domain redirection found mydomain.com/store and then it redirect to mydomain.com/store/store and so on. Using above login you can work on php SESSION and solve the issue and there is not dependency on user side.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create `index.html` that contain this meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url=http://www.example.com/store">
```

Change `example.com` to your domain.

Comment: Won't this break the browser back button functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I decided that a redirect was not the answer here, so I moved the Magento store from the subdirectory /store to root. I followed these instructions:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/move-magento-to-another-directory/

But I copied files from store rather than moved them. This way you can revert back quickly if anything goes wrong.